# Duvidas sobre alocação Dinâmica

Tags: c

Como consigo em C pegar uma variável, como no exemplo abaixo, fazer com que N = vetor.

Caso eu for jogar N em outra função e colocar dentro de um `for`, e depois quiser realocar o valor de vetor aumentando N vezes. E assim aumentando N proposicionalmente. Para poder inserir mais dados no laço

E outra duvida como eu passo essa variavel vetor por referenciana função?

```
scanf("%i", &N);  
vetor = malloc(N * sizeof(int)); //vetor de struct
```